# I want to know about connection between BES and Blackberry phone

Tags: blackberry

I want to know how connection is established between my BB phone and BES?
Is connection based on my mobile service provider or some other thing?

Can u tell me ,how is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a Blackberry is used in a corporate environment. Using the Blackberry MDS Dataservice a connection looks like this. The datastream is encrypted and compressed.

[image]
<sub>(source: [blackberry.com](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/services/bb_mds_arch_large.gif))</sub>

For a quick overview I recommend this video by Research in Motion.

[Network Transports](http://www.blackberry.com/DevMediaLibrary/view.do?name=NetworkingTransports)

Answer (score 1):

The connection between a Blackberry and the BES can be carried over the wireless carrier network, to the internet, to the RIM operations centre then by the internet to the BES; or by Wi-Fi to the internet to RIM to the internet to the BES; or by Wi-Fi directly to the BES (if the BES is local to the Wi-Fi connection); or by USB to a PC with Desktop Manager via the local area network to the BES.